# What could be the cause for :Failed to generate AWS EC2 Instance Types: WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling

Auto scaler failing with the below error.

Procedure followed for [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler)

```
aws_cloud_provider.go:369] Failed to generate AWS EC2 Instance Types: WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials

cluster autoscaler failed to generate aws ec2 instance types: unable to load ec2 instance type list
```

Comment: Tip1:https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-load-balancer-webidentityerr/

Comment: tip2 : shutdown and start-up auto-scaling groups

Answer (score 2):

Add `"ec2:DescribeInstanceTypes"` permission to your `<AmazonEKSClusterAutoscalerPolicy>` IAM policy.
Then restart the Autoscaller deployment.

```
kubectl -n kube-system rollout restart deployment.apps/cluster-autoscaler
```

This worked for me.